.Net 8 Global Exception Handler not writing response.Body
I'm attempting to write a couple APIs and want to have a standard location to handle any uncaught exceptions. This handler needs to do two things, format and log the exception and then return a standardized response body. I've been able to accomplish the logging and upon doing research have attempted multiple ways to write my object to the response body, but whether I call through postman or another api, I never get a response body back. At this point I'm in need of some help to determine why I am seeing this behavior and what may be wrong with my solutions.
I've attempted 3 different implementations of the exception handler (custom middleware, IExceptionHandler custom class, directly writing  app.UseExceptionHandler lambda) and multiple ways of writing to the body with success. I have changed the response.StatusCode and can get different ones back but never get the body. I've also attempted changing the order in which my middleware/exceptionHandler are called in Program.cs to determine if any additional middlewares may be modifying it afterwards which has also returned the same result.
I first went with a middleware implementation which can be found below as it was the way I was most familiar with for implementing global exception handling.
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;
    private SecurityHeadersPolicy _policy;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, SecurityHeadersPolicy policy)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogger logger)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError((int)CommonLogCode.UnhandledError, "An unhandled error occurred.", ex);
            context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderConstants.TransactionIdKey, out var transactionId);


            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            var response = new DeveloperMessageResponse()
            {
                ErrorCode = string.Format("{0:0000}", CommonLogCode.UnhandledError),
                ReferenceId = transactionId,
                DeveloperMessage = "An unhandled exception occurred.",
                DisplayMessage = "An unexpected error occurred."
            };

            IHeaderDictionary headers = context.Response.Headers;

            foreach (var headerValuePair in _policy.SetHeaders)
            {
                headers[headerValuePair.Key] = headerValuePair.Value;
            }

            foreach (var header in _policy.RemoveHeaders)
            {
                headers.Remove(header);
            }

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(response));

        }
    }

}

When I had no success with this I did some further research and found in .Net 8 the recommended approach was to implement a custom IExceptionHandler:
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public GlobalExceptionHandler(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogError((int)CommonLogCode.UnhandledError, "An unhandled error occurred.", exception);
        
        httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderConstants.TransactionIdKey, out var transactionId);

        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        IHeaderDictionary headers = httpContext.Response.Headers;

        var response = new DeveloperMessageResponse()
        {
            ErrorCode = string.Format("{0:0000}", (int)CommonLogCode.UnhandledError),
            ReferenceId = transactionId,
            DeveloperMessage = "An unhandled exception occurred.",
            DisplayMessage = "An unexpected error occurred."
        };

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(response));
        
        return true;
    }

When I could not get this to work I then attempted the lambda approach in Program.cs which is the current implementation I have. I attempted using httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync, httpContext.Response.WriteAsync, and httpContext.Response.Body.Write to attempt to get a body returned:
app.UseExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerApp =>
{
    exceptionHandlerApp.Run(async context =>
    {
        var logger = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
        var policy = securityPolicy.Build();
        var exceptionHandlerFeature =
           context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        logger.LogError((int)CommonLogCode.UnhandledError, "An unhandled error occurred.", exceptionHandlerFeature?.Error);

        context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderConstants.TransactionIdKey, out var transactionId);
        //context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        IHeaderDictionary headers = context.Response.Headers;

        foreach (var headerValuePair in policy.SetHeaders)
        {
            headers[headerValuePair.Key] = headerValuePair.Value;
        }

        foreach (var header in policy.RemoveHeaders)
        {
            headers.Remove(header);
        }
        var response = new DeveloperMessageResponse()
        {
            ErrorCode = string.Format("{0:0000}", (int)CommonLogCode.UnhandledError),
            ReferenceId = transactionId,
            DeveloperMessage = "An unhandled exception occurred.",
            DisplayMessage = "An unexpected error occurred."
        };
        //var responseBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(response));
        //await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
         
        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(response));
        //await context.Response.CompleteAsync();

    });
});

Here is my Program.cs. This does have comments where I was attempting to setup each implementation as well as the current implementation of the lambda.
   var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
   builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options => { options.AddServerHeader = false; options.AllowResponseHeaderCompression = false; });
   

   // Add services to the container.
   builder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddApiExplorer();
   builder.Services.AddControllers()
       .AddJsonOptions(options =>
       {
           options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
           options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
       });

   builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
   {
       options.ForwardedHeaders =
           ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
   });

   builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
   builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
   builder.Services.AddApiAndSwaggerVersioningconfigurations();
   builder.Services.AddAutoMapperDependencies("UserAPI*.dll");
   builder.Services.AddFrameworkDependencies();
   builder.Services.AddApplicationDependencies("UserAPI*.dll");
   //builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<GlobalExceptionHandler>();


   var app = builder.Build();
   var securityPolicy = new SecurityHeadersBuilder().AddDefaultAPISecurePolicy();
   //app.UseExceptionMiddleware(securityPolicy);
   
   app.UseForwardedHeaders();
   //app.UseExceptionHandler(opt => { });
   
   app.UseExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerApp =>
   {
       exceptionHandlerApp.Run(async context =>
       {
           var logger = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
           var policy = securityPolicy.Build();
           var exceptionHandlerFeature =
              context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
           logger.LogError((int)CommonLogCode.UnhandledError, "An unhandled error occurred.", exceptionHandlerFeature?.Error);

           context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderConstants.TransactionIdKey, out var transactionId);
           //context.Response.Clear();
           context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
           context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
           IHeaderDictionary headers = context.Response.Headers;

           foreach (var headerValuePair in policy.SetHeaders)
           {
               headers[headerValuePair.Key] = headerValuePair.Value;
           }

           foreach (var header in policy.RemoveHeaders)
           {
               headers.Remove(header);
           }
           var response = new DeveloperMessageResponse()
           {
               ErrorCode = string.Format("{0:0000}", (int)CommonLogCode.UnhandledError),
               ReferenceId = transactionId,
               DeveloperMessage = "An unhandled exception occurred.",
               DisplayMessage = "An unexpected error occurred."
           };
           //var responseBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(response));
           //await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
            
           await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(response));
           //await context.Response.CompleteAsync();

       });
   });
   app.UseResponseSecurityHeaderMiddleware(securityPolicy);

   if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
   {
       app.UseSwagger();
       app.UseSwaggerUI();
   }
   else
   {
       app.UseHsts();
   }

   app.UseHttpMiddleware();
   app.UsePerformanceTrackingMiddleware();

   app.UseHttpsRedirection();
   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseAuthorization();

   int suppressVersionsBelow = 0;
   int.TryParse(builder.Configuration[ConfigConstants.SuppressVersionsBelow], out suppressVersionsBelow);
   var versioningProvider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
   app.ConfigureSwaggerUI(versioningProvider, suppressVersionsBelow);

   app.MapControllers();

   app.Run();

I've also attempted to configure and use different hosts (kestrel, IIS, Docker) to try to determine if they may be modifying the response but that also did not make a difference.
Postman Request Headers & Response Body/Status
I would expect the body to be the json version of this object and it currently is blank:
{
    ErrorCode = string.Format("{0:0000}", (int)CommonLogCode.UnhandledError),
    ReferenceId = transactionId,
    DeveloperMessage = "An unhandled exception occurred.",
    DisplayMessage = "An unexpected error occurred."
}


What behavior do you get as a result? Is there an exception thrown on body write? Or is the written body ignored? Is your exception handling logic actually executed by the application under debugger? Please provide a minimal application that reproduces your problem and include the code that throws the exception. As of now, it is impossible to tell why the code does not run when there is not exception thrown anywhere in the sample code, yet there is a lot of other code that might interfere.

It appears that the way I was testing this was the problem. I was manually creating and throwing an error to test that it was handled properly. In this situation I still cannot and never do get a body back; however, I ran into an actual unexpected error and it was handled correctly. I'm not sure why these are handled differently but it is working.
